# Using two variable in *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

```
<ion-col size="12" *ngFor="let day of weekdays">
     <h5>{{day | titlecase }}</h5>
     <ion-grid fixed>
         <ion-row>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let item of category.menu_items">
         <ion-col sizeLg="4" size="12" *ngIf="item.menu_item_books['0'].{{day}}">
```

I have a data like this:

```
item.menu_item_books['0'].monday: false
```

I want using to use this data for showing element. I create an array:

```
weekdays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];
```

I want using weekdays array's element in `*ngIf`. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you re-phraze the question? What do you want the if statement to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write it like that

```
*ngIf="item.menu_item_books['0'][day]"
```